# I need to add 2 more slide on top last(yellow) and bottom last(yellow) with same effect replacing with front img

Tags: click, move, slide

[image]

please find live link here...

please increase the preview are so you can see best view of slide...

I need to add 2 more slide on top last(yellow) and bottom last(yellow) with same effect replacing with front img..

suitable reply appreciated...

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/vik/y1bfc8du/1/

Comment: please find the live link here..

Comment: please increase the preview area so you can see best view of slide...

Comment: Amended image for display.

Comment: thanks for update ManoDestra..
please have a look if any correction then please let me know..